# Problems with calculated fields

Tags: c#, field, calculation

I'm having problems with calculated fields. I'd like to create something like this:

```
[Column("birthyear")]
private int? _BirthYear;
public int? BirthYear { 
   get {
      return _BirthYear;
   }
   set {
      _BirthYear = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
   }
}
public int? Age {
   get {
      if (BirthYear != null) return DateTime.Now.Year - (int)BirthYear;
         return 0;
   }
   set {
      BirthYear = DateTime.Now.Year - value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

But when I run the application I get the following error:

> Unknown column 'Extent.Age' in 'field list'.

How can I properly implement this functionality?

Comment: Maybe the attribute ``[Column("Age")]`` is missing.

Comment: Hi, can not be, as Age is not a field in the database. It should not be persistent as it is calculated from the birthyear..

Answer (score 0):

it look like issue was in reading it from database.

Can you try the below one.

```
[NotMapped]
public int? Age {
....
....
```